# Regular values and manifolds with boundary

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

**Question:** Let $X^m$ and $Y^n$ differentiable manifolds. $f:X\rightarrow Y$ a differentiable map. Show that if $\partial X=\emptyset$, $y\in Reg(f)$ and $f^{-1}(y)\neq\emptyset$, then $y\not\in\partial Y.$

$\\$

If there is $y\in\partial Y.$ Then if $F:U\subset\mathbb H^n\rightarrow V$, $p\in U$ such that  $F(p)=y$, then $p\in \partial \mathbb H^n$.

Let $x\in f^{-1}(y)$, my idea is to proof that $x\in \partial X$, which is a contradiction.

As $f$ is differentiable, let $G:W\subset\mathbb R^m\rightarrow Z$ a parametrization of $X$, $q\in W$ with $G(q)=x$. Then, $F^{-1}\circ f\circ G$ is differentiable at $q$.

And what else can i do?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Think about what the map $f$ does to points around $x$.  Also, recall what a submersion means for the dimensions of your two spaces.

Addendum:

Everything you did was correct.  You just need to push the conclusion out of what you already know.  And that comes from the [submersion theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submersion_%28mathematics%29#Local_normal_form). So we can assume that these open sets you mentioned line up in such a way that $F^{-1}\circ f \circ G (x_1,\ldots,x_m)=(x_1,\ldots ,x_n)$ since $m\geq n$. Then all you have to do is notice that the open set $W$ was open in euclidean space, while $U$ was an open nhood of a boundary point in the half-space.  Personally I would say you have reached your contradiction.  If you want to be more thorough, you can look at the last coordinate of your points in $U$ and notice they are all positive...  I will leave that to you.

Comment: Hi N. Owad, thanks for your help. If $z$ is a point close to $x$, then, by continuity, $f(z)$ is close to $y$. Also, $dim f^{-1}(y)=m-n$, but i do not see how it can help.

Comment: @Miguemate So, an open neighborhood of $x$ is mapped to an open neighborhood of $f(x)$. But what do we know about $f(x)$?

Comment: $f(x)=y$, $y\in \partial Y$ a regular value

Comment: And what do open nhoods of boundary points look like?

Comment: I have this. For every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $y\in f(B_{\delta}(x))\subset B_{\epsilon}(y)=V_y\cap \partial Y$, $V_y$ an open subset of $\mathbb R^l$, assuming $Y\subset\mathbb R^l$.

Comment: What you described there is an open nhood in the boundary of $Y$. What $f$ does is map into all of $Y$.  So, could an open set of $X$ be mapped smoothly to a set with boundary in $Y$?

Comment: I see your point, but i do not know how to use the fact that $y$ is a regular valeu, or that $df_x$ is surjective.